# scan col for matching text and paste results in another column

Tags: excel, if-statement, vba

I need to scan Col B for any values that have the same left characters that are found in cell AL2, the length of the string is found in AR1. If the left value in Col B matches the value  in AL2 I need to copy the values in that row from Col B to col G. copied into Col At, starting a AT6 and continuing down until there until all values in Col C have been checked. First picture is data that will be scanned, second picture is what I want the macro to spit out

Here is the modified macro that I recorded. I am getting an runtime 13 error on the IF statement. Any ideas on how to clean this up ?

[image: data to be scanned]
[image: data copied from scanned data]

```
        Sub GenerateSummaryPage()
'

' scans B column for combiner box numbers
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim dlen As String


    Worksheets("HR-Cal").Activate
    dlen = Worksheets("HR-Cal").Range("AR2")
    r = ActiveCell.Row
    For lrow = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row To 7 Step -1

    'checks curent row for box name in cell AL2
    'copies values from col B to col G in that row to into Col AT, starting at AS6
    If Left(Cells(lrow, "B"), dlen) = ActiveSheet.Range("AL2").Text Then Range("B" & r).Rows.Select
    'If Left(Cells(lrow, "B"), dlen) = Range("AL2").Value Then Range("B" & r & ":G" & r).Select
        Selection.Copy
    Range("AT100000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial (xlPasteAll)

    Next lrow

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
'insert rows for inverter headers

End Sub
```

Comment: I think you meant `Range("B" & r & ":G" & r).rows.Select`

Comment: @findwindow I made that adjustment and I got the same error, however removing .rows and running macro it ran with no error but didn't copy the data from B:G and is stil lonly pasting into that one cell. Do i need to use a loop to start at AT6 and add a row for each value?

Comment: Your loop should work. It's `Range("AS6").Select` that's the problem. You need to make that variable. Something like `cells(lrow,45).select` (45 is column AS?). Edit: why are you looping backwards?

Comment: This is likely beyond your concern but try to avoid using select and copy/paste.

Comment: I try to avoid select and copy paste but I am still dusting all the cobwebs off my macro knowledge / learning as much new stuff as I can. I have never really done a loop before so I guess i didn't know i was doing it backwards

Comment: Your loop is `step -1` meaning backwards but should still work. You can't lock in one single range for paste. `Range("AT100000")` even with offset will also lock in the cell below that range. You need it to be dynamic. Like `cells(row,column)` .

Comment: Might also want to change `Range("B" & r)` to `Range("B" & lrow)`

Comment: Do you need formatting?

Comment: @findwindow I do not need formatting, I have a more code that will apply formatting after I generate this list. The list is step one of about five steps.

Answer (score 1):

You should try this.

```
If Left(Cells(lrow, "B"), dlen) = ActiveSheet.Range("AL2").Text Then
   Range(Cells(lrow, "B"), Cells(lrow, "G")).Value = Range(Cells(lrow, "AT"), Cells(lrow, "AY")).Value
End if
```

If this doesn't work you, before the if you could try to check the value of lrow and dlen to make to sure they have a correct value.

Let me know if that works for you

Comment: That also works, and I had called out the wrong cell originally but  now I cannot get the code to paste the data I need into the desired  cells. I have updated the code to the latest verison

Comment: If I understand correctly you want to copy the rows A to T and paste it somewhere?

Comment: I need an if stament to check col B for a specific text, when it finds that text it needs to copy the data in b to g of that row, into col AT. Starting at AT6 and working its way down the column with each time it finds a match in the B column

Comment: I modified my answer to fit your requirements.

Comment: @phil652 you have it backwards XD

Comment: @PHIL652  @ findwondow I tried this and it kinda works. I get the value from col B in to col AU but I don't get the other values ( col c-g) and it doesn't start in AT6 and paste each new value below the last value it found. I may try to alter the macro or try an index match match formula

Comment: You should update your code so we cant see whats going on

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't need formatting, I think you want something like this...

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.WorkSheets("HR-Cal")
dlen = 2 'change this
lrow = ws.Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 7 To lrow

'checks curent row for box name in cell AL2
'copies values from col B to col G in that row to into Col AT, starting at AS6
If Left(Cells(i, "B"), dlen) = ws.Range("M2").Text Then 'change M2
'Range("B" & i).Rows.Select
'If Left(Cells(lrow, "B"), dlen) = Range("AL2").Value Then Range("B" & r & ":G" & r).Select
'Selection.Copy
Range(Cells(i, 10), Cells(i, 15)).Value = Range(Cells(i, 2), Cells(i, 7)).Value 'change columns
'Range("AT100000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial (xlPasteAll)
End If

Next i
```

Comment: Uh adjust columns/cells as necessary. I altered them for my own testing.

Comment: sorry had to step out for a meeting. I will modify code above and see if it works